# How to store ID in database but shows description on the index page?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my question is how to store the policy_category_id in database but shows the description at index page as I refer the data from the first module.
I have two database

Database name - (bit_app_policy_category) with columns
1. id
2. code
3. description
4. parent_id
5. status

index page code

```
 <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['code']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['description']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['parent_id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['status']}}</td>

                    <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('categoryController@destroy',$row['id'])}}">
                            {{  csrf_field()    }}
                            {{  method_field('DELETE')}}

                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"  />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

2nd database name - (company_policy) with columns
1.policy_category_id
2.policy_title
3.version_no
4.policy_details
5.file_path
6.publish

Here is my code ( bit_app_policy_category )

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bit_app_policy_category_desc">Description<span<p><font color="#F05340"> *</font></p></label></span>
                <input id="bit_app_policy_category_desc" type="text" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter the Description" />
            </div>

            <input  type="hidden"
                    name="parent_id"
                    value="{{ $parent_id ?? ''}}"
            />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bit_app_policy_category_parent">Parent Category<span<p><font color="#F05340"> *</font></p></label></span>
                <select id="bit_app_policy_category_parent"  name="parent_id" class="form-control">
                    <option value="{{null}}">--Select Category--</option>
                    @foreach($parents as $parent)
                        @if ($parent-> status != 'Freeze')
                            <option value="{{ $parent->id}}" >{{$parent->description}} </option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

second database ( company_policy )

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="company_policy_policy_category_id">Policy's Category<span<p><font color="#F05340"> *</font></p></label></span>
                <select id="company_policy_policy_category_id"  name="policy_category_id" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($parents as $parent)
                        @if ($parent-> status != 'Freeze')
                            <option value="{{ $parent->description}}" >{{$parent->description}} </option>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

Index page code

```
  <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['policy_category_id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['policy_title']}} </td>
                    <td>{{$row['version_no']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['file_path']}}</td>

                    <td><a href="{{action('policyController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
```

Comment: By database name do you mean table name? Can you please edit your question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE company_policy` and others nicely formatted like your code. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I couldn't show the picture ,if there is a picture , its easy to be understand